# Laravel ingresar imagen en crud

Tags: php, laravel, crud

tengo una duda si me pudiesen ayudar estoy tratando de ingresar una imagen en un CRUD generado en laravel , la imagen se guarda bien con su extensión en uploads pero en la base de datos se guarda con extensión .temp , no se a que se deberá .
De antemano muchas gracias.

```html
 public function store(Request $request)
    {  
        request()->validate(Instrumento::$rules);

        
        if($request->hasfile('foto')){

            $instrumento['foto']=$request->file('foto')->store('uploads','public');
        
       
        }
        $instrumento = Instrumento::create($request->all());
         
        

        return redirect()->route('instrumentos.index')
            ->with('success', 'Instrumento creado con exito.');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tomar el nombre y la extensión original del archivo enviado, guardarlos en una variable, y mover el archivo a la carpeta que quieres, luego agregar el nombre que guardaste en la variable y agregarlo al `array` de datos

```
public function store(Request $request) {  
    request()->validate(Instrumento::$rules);
    
    $data=$request->except(['foto']);
    if($request->hasfile('foto')){
        $file=$request->file('foto');
        $arrayFileName=explode("\\", $file->getPathname());
        $tmpName=end($arrayFileName);
        $image='uploads/'.str_replace('.tmp', '', $tmpName);
        $file->store('uploads','public');
        $data['foto']=$image;
    }
    $instrumento = Instrumento::create($data);
         
    return redirect()->route('instrumentos.index')->with('success', 'Instrumento creado con exito.');
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142040/discussion-on-answer-by-bryant-jimenez-laravel-ingresar-imagen-en-crud).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un helper para realizar esto:

Crear una carpeta llamada Helpers el archivo que sea llamado Uploader.php

```
class Uploader {
public static function uploadFile(string $key, string $path): string {
    $fileName = self::generateFileName($key);
    request()->file($key)->storeAs($path, $fileName);
    return $fileName;
 }

public static function removeFile(string $path, string $fileName) {
    Storage::delete(sprintf('%s/%s', $path, $fileName));
}

protected static function generateFileName(string $key): string {
    $extension = request()->file($key)->getClientOriginalExtension();
    return sprintf('%s-%s.%s', auth()->id(), now()->timestamp, $extension);
  }
}
```

En el método store puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
 public function storeCourse(Request $request){

    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $file = null;
        if ($request->hasFile('foto')) {
            $file = UploaderImageCourse::uploadFile('foto', 'uploads');
        }
        $instrumento = Instrumento::create($this->instrumentoInput($file));

        DB::commit();
        session()->flash("message", ["success", __("Instrumento creado satisfactoriamente")]);
        return redirect(route('home'));
    } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
        session()->flash("message", ["danger", $exception->getMessage()]);
        return back();
    }
}
```

Yo no te recomiendo usar $request->all() por lo siguiente; un ataque de asignación masiva permite insertar registros no deseados en tu base de datos, es decir, una columna name que tú no estás mostrando en tu formulario pero tampoco protegiendo de asignación masiva, puede ser manipulada y recibir algo diferente.

Puedes crear un método siguiente:

```
protected function instrumentoInput(string $file = null): array {
    return [
        "user_id" => request("user_id"),
        "title" => request("title"),
        "short_description" => request("short_description"),
        "presentation" => request("presentation"),
        "duration" => request("duration"),
        "long_description" => request("long_description"),
        "picture" => $file
    ];
}
```

Así de igual forma implementar tu propio request, llamado InstrumentoRequest y validar cada campo.